# Is there a way to catch or simulate a custom key press in C#?

Tags: c#, function, macros, key, simulate

1) I have a Razer BlackWidow Chroma, which has about 5 macro keys on the side. I was wondering if you could simulate, or even catch these key presses.

```
private void AddAll()
    {
        var allPossibleKeys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys));
        foreach (var currentKey in allPossibleKeys)
        {
            Keys key = (Keys)currentKey;
            if (key != Keys.None)
            {
                gkh.HookedKeys.Add(key);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have this to catch regular keys into a global key handler.

2)  This could also fix my problem. If I could press the Function key (NOT F1, F2, F3 ect. Function key common a laptop) (also not in my list of keys) + 1 simultaneously (acting as one key press) then I could fix it.

Answering either of these would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) that catches keypresses/mouse clicks and can perform a Macro based on your settings.

I also found a [post](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/282-fn-key-on-a-notebook/) related to key bindings on a laptop's Fn keypress.  The key-combination varies per laptop.

Comment: I'm trying to create a program that changes my keyboard display profile (FN  + 1 or Macro_1 Button) whenever my computer goes idle after 15 minutes. Above I have parts of my program that catches keystroke of any "standard" key. Everything functions except for the usage of the profile keys. I need to know how to simulate custom keys.